# Inverting a product

Tags: products

Can anyone explain why $$\prod^{0}_{n=5}\frac{1}{f(n)}=f(1)f(2)f(3)f(4)$$ in other words is there some relationship or identity for dealing with inverses in products.

Comment: You left out a lot of context. What is $f$?

Comment: Is it $\prod_{n=0}^5$? (I mean $n$ in your product is running for $n=5,4,3,2,1,0$?)

Comment: Note that $$\prod_{n=0}^5 \frac{1}{f(n)} = \frac{1}{\prod_{n=0}^5f(n)}= \prod_{k=1}^4 f(k) \iff 1= f(0)f(5)\prod_{k=1}^4 f(k)^2=f(0)f(5)\left(\prod_{k=1}^4 f(k)\right)^2$$.

Comment: Thanks, why is that second equality true, is there a proof on the internet?

Comment: $$\prod_{n=0}^5 \frac{1}{f(n)}=\frac{1}{f(0)}\cdot\frac{1}{f(1)}\cdot\frac{1}{f(2)}\cdot \frac{1}{f(3)}\cdot\frac{1}{f(4)}\cdot\frac{1}{f(5)} = \frac{1}{f(0)f(1)f(2)f(3)f(4)f(5)} = \frac{1}{\prod_{n=0}^5f(n)}$$

Comment: Sorry isnt't $\prod^{4}_{k=1}f(k)=f(1)f(2)f(3)f(4)$ so i dont see why it is equal

Comment: @user3261646 this is the equality you wrote in the OP, namely: $$\prod_{n=0}^5 \frac{1}{f(n)} = \prod_{k=1}^4 f(k)$$

Comment: Please provide some context for where you found this identity. What @Surb gave you is an equivalent condition, but either may or may not be true depending on the properties of $f$.

Comment: @A.P. You are right! However I think the OP basically wants to understand the relation $$\left( \prod_{k=1}^m x_k\right)^{-1}= \prod_{k=1}^m x_k^{-1}$$ for some $x_1,\ldots,x_m\in \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend the general rule $$\prod_{k=l}^mf(k)\prod_{k=m+1}^nf(k)=\prod_{k=l}^nf(k),$$which is obviously true when $l\leqslant m< n$, to cases when $l$, $m$, and $n$ are in some other order, then your result follows (assuming that $f(k) \neq0$ in the range). However, not everybody adheres to this convention. Instead, a commonly adopted convention is simply "an empty product is unity": that is, $$\prod_{k=m}^nf(k)=1$$ whenever $n<m$ and not just when $n=m-1$.

**Added:**  If you set $l=1$, $m=0$, and $n=1$ in the first identity, you get $$\prod_{k=1}^0f(k)\prod_{k=1}^1f(k)=\prod_{k=1}^1f(k),$$for all $f$. That is, $$\prod_{k=1}^0f(k)=1$$for all $f$. Using this result, substitute $l=1$, $m=4$, and $n=0$ in the first identity and you get the result in the question.

Comment: How does the identity (rule) you wrote apply to the OP's problem?

Comment: @A.P.: The question was wrongly edited. I have reset it to the OP's actual problem. I have also expanded the explanation to address your query.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this usage? The well definition of products from $m$ to $n$ with $n<m$ is not clear to me.

Comment: @A.P. The well definition of products from $m$ to $n$ with $n<m$ is not an issue that arises much in mathematical literature, as far as I know. Usually a product over an "invalid" range is considered "a product of no terms" and set equal to 1. Similarly a sum of no terms is zero. But it is perhaps more interesting to define these strange products (or sums) so that they fit in smoothly with the usual laws of arithmetic, in the same way that fractions and negative numbers were invented. If you do this, you get $$\prod_{k=m}^nf(k):=1/\prod_{k=n+1}^{m-1}f(k)$$ when $n<m$.